# CoreData: how to get the total count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

In my data model I have two entities:
Category and Item.

**Category**
attr: name
rel: parent (Destination: Category, Inverse: subCategories)
rel: subCategories (Destination: Category, Inverse: parent, To-Many Relationship)
rel: items (Destination: Item, Inverse: category, To-Many Relationship)

**Item**
attr: title
rel: category  (Destination: Category, Inverse: items, To-Many Relationship)

Got the following TVC's: Root, Category, and Item
Root displays all Category objects with no parent
Category displays all Category objects with a certain parent object
Item displays all Item objects with a certain category

Example data:

```
Top Cat 1
- Sub cat 1
 - Item 1
 - Item 2
 - Item 3
 - Item 4
- Sub cat 2
 - Item 1
- Sub cat 3
 - Item 1
- Sub cat 4
 - Item 1
 - Item 2
- Sub cat 5
Top Cat 2
- Sub cat 1
 - Item 1
 - Item 2
 - Item 3
- Sub cat 2
 - Item 1
- Sub cat 3
 - Item 1
```

**So how do I get the total number of items per "Top Cat" when in the Root TVC?**
If I want to know the number of "Sub cat"s I can use the following keyPath: "subCategories.@count" but something like "subCategories.items.@count" does not work.

Hope you can help me.

Cheers
-Me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways get the count:

1. Fire a fetch request for the top category in question, and from that object get the count of entities in it's sub-categories relationship set. The downside of this approach is that it will cause `CoreData` to fetch the relationship property from the store, fetching every object associated with that relationship.  e.g.

   `NSManagedObject *topCat = [context performFetch:topCatFetchRequest];
   NSInteger count = topCat.subCategories.count;`
2. Use raw `SQLite` API's to query the data store directly (note this is much faster).
3. Probably the easiest, use `NSManagedObjectContext` `countForFetchRequest:`, which will return the number of objects matching a given fetch request.